# WPF Storyboard's DoubleAnimation behaves unexpectedly

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF Storyboard to slide my window from the right corner of the screen and then to hide it again.

I have three problems:

1. If you catch window that is currently sliding right it slows down.
2. Sometimes(very rarely, so it's hard to find the reason) window only hides its half and animation stops. If you enter the window by a mouse and leave again it hides the rest of it.
3. Sometimes when I reach the edge of the screen to show the window nothing happens for a while and then window slides very fast to the correct position.

MouseOnEdge is my custom event which is fired when mouse reaches the right corner of the screen.

That's my XAML code:

```
<local:CustomWindow.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:CustomWindow.CustomMouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="SlideWindowOff">
                <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="ShellViewWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left"
                Duration="0:0:0.75"
                AccelerationRatio="0.5"
                From="{Binding WindowLeft}"
                To="{Binding WindowLeftHidden}"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:CustomWindow.MouseOnEdge">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="SlideWindowOn">
                <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="ShellViewWindow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left"
                Duration="0:0:0.75"
                AccelerationRatio="0.5"
                From="{Binding WindowLeft}"
                To="{Binding WindowLeftUnhidden}"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</local:CustomWindow.Triggers>
```

Why is something like this happening? The main problem here is when storyboard hides only half of the window and it's going to be the biggest problem for users.